# Enable SSH autocomplete for function which calls SSH

Tags: bash, bash-completion

I created a simple function in `.bashrc` to `ssh` into a specific machine and enter a specific `tmux` session:

```
# Function to ssh to a machine with tmux
connect() {
    local host=$1
    local session=${2:-main}
    # Check if tmux session exists
    if ssh -q "$host" "tmux has-session -t $session 2>/dev/null"; then
        ssh -t "$host" "tmux attach -t $session"
    else
        # Create tmux session if it doesn't exist
        ssh -t "$host" "tmux new-session -s $session"
    fi
}
```

Everything works so well, but previously when I typed `ssh` and pressed `TAB` I got autocomplete for the existing machines that I have defined in the `.ssh/config` file, and am looking for a way to enable that autocomplete for the new `connect` alias.

Comment: see output of `complete -p ssh`

Comment: @pynexj thanks in my case it was just `complete -F _ssh connect`

Comment: I changed the terminology here; there is no "piping" going on at any point. This term very specifically refers to connecting the standard output of one process as the standard input of another.

Answer (score 0):

In my case this did the  trick:

```
complete -F _ssh connect
```

Enabling autocomplete of another command for example `cd` will be like this

```
complete -F _cd somecommand
```

```
# Function to ssh to a machine with tmux
connect() {
   local host=$1
   local session=${2:-main}
   # Check if tmux session exists
   if ssh -q "$host" "tmux has-session -t $session 2>/dev/null"; then
       ssh -t "$host" "tmux attach -t $session"
   else
       # Create tmux session if it doesn't exist
       ssh -t "$host" "tmux new-session -s $session"
   fi
}

# Custom completion function for the connect function
_connect_completion() {
   local cur=${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}
   local hosts=$(grep '^Host' ~/.ssh/config | awk '{print $2}')

   COMPREPLY=($(compgen -W "$hosts" -- "$cur"))
}

# Register the custom completion function for the connect command
complete -F _connect_completion connect
```